# Present specific view controller in didReceiveRemoteNotification with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, push-notification

When a user taps a push notification, I want them to be taken to a specific table view controller in my app. This table view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, which is embedded in a tab bar controller (my root view controller). The image shown below visualizes this.

[image]

The root view Tab Bar Controller has a storyboard ID of "HomeVC" and a class name of "HomeViewController", the Navigation Controller has a storyboard ID of "SettingsNavigationVC", and the Table View Controller has a storyboard ID of "SettingsTableVC" and a class name of "SettingsNavigationVC".

I have push notifications working. By working, I mean I can send a message from a device and receive it on another device, but when the receiver taps the notification I can't seem to get any other view controller to open other than the root view controller. According to the [push notification guide](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-responding/iOS) I'm using, I'm using the following code in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {

    let rootVC = self.window!.rootViewController
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        let settingsTableVC = SettingsTableViewController()
        rootVC?.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsTableVC, animated: false)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, or what must I do to present the right view controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC") as! UITabBarController
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
    rootVC.selectedIndex = 2 // Index of the tab bar item you want to present, as shown in question it seems is item 2
    self.window!.rootViewController = rootVC
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to push to the specific view controller, you must replace below line:

Yours:

```
rootVC?.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsTableVC, animated: false)
```

Mine:

```
rootVC?.visibleViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsTableVC, animated: true)
```

And for presenting any view controller, you must use this:

```
rootVC?.visibleViewController.navigationController?.presentViewController(settingsTableVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```