# How do I get the string name of a storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I've already looked at the following for guidance to no avail:

[How to know the current storyboard name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723732/how-to-know-the-current-storyboard-name)

I am trying to open a specific view controller using my storyboard from a remote notification based off of the following answer:

[Present specific view controller in didReceiveRemoteNotification with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910129/present-specific-view-controller-in-didreceiveremotenotification-with-swift)

```
    let mvc = MainViewController()
    let storyBoardNameString = mvc.storyboard. //<-proposed solution? Nothing from auto complete shows up
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardNameString , bundle: nil) 
    storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("some-view-controller")
```

I've checked the "File inspector", "Quick help inspector", "Identity inspector", "Attributes inspector", "Size inspector", and even the "Connections inspector" with no luck there either.

When I selected a view controller on my storyboard and tried to find the name of the current storyboard I was only able to find the view's Storyboard ID, not the name of the storyboard however.

Any solution would be greatly appreciated, otherwise I will try to find another way to accomplish my task.

Comment: If you can get the `storyboard` from the `mvc` object then you don't need to name of it. You already have the `storyboard` in the first place..

Comment: Probably a pointless question but I suppose I would have to use a viewController on the `mvc` to access the `mvc` correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My colleague just informed me it's the name of the file without the ".storyboard" extension. Regards.

Comment: This doesn't change the fact that you don't need the storyboard's name if you already have any view controller instantiated from it.

Comment: I know, but it still answers the original question :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my answer is not right to your question, but you can take a look and think about it.

Make a payload format, and create the specific UIViewController with it.

```
let payload = ["storyboard" : "StoryboadNameYouWant", "viewcontroller" : "ViewControllerName", "parameters" : "YourParameters"]


func handlePayload(payload: Dictionary<String, String>) {
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: payload["storyboard"]!, bundle: nil)
     let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(payload["viewcontroller"]!)
     // present vc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code it may helps you.**

```
let mvc = MainViewController()
let storyBoardNameString = mvc.restorationIdentifier!//it will give identifier
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardNameString , bundle: nil) 
storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("some-view-controller")
```